# Creating a custom tab navigation component

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetify-tabs

I'm trying to create a custom tab component based on Vuetify but I'm having trouble trying to get the component to recognize the `items` object I've defined... Being quite new to Vue and Vuetify, I'm not able to determine what could be happening and how to resolve it. Being a custom component, I'm not sure if I can replicate it on an IDE like codepen to simulate it...

Could anyone please assist with telling me how to fix this code such that my `items` object can be read and rendered into tabs?

The main calling page *(Demo.vue)*:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="9">
        <v-container>
          <h2 class="mt-6 mb-2">
            Demo
          </h2>
          <p class="pt-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Vero temporibus repudiandae, quia consequatur, aperiam reiciendis sint eos cum voluptas sunt, libero aliquid cumque iste, accusantium quam assumenda illo quas eum.</p>
            <v-row class="pa-5 d-flex justify-center">
              <TabNavigation v-model="tab"/>
            </v-row>
          <p class="pt-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt consequuntur dolores modi perspiciatis iste? Reprehenderit odio illo eligendi fugit cumque dolor, debitis quidem quod illum repellendus veritatis, veniam, maiores labore.</p>
        </v-container>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </div>
</template> 
<script>
import TabNavigation from './TabNavigation-temp';
export default {
  name: "Demo",
  data () {
    return {
      tab: 1,
      items: [
        { tab: 'One', content: 'Tab 1 Content' },
        { tab: 'Two', content: 'Tab 2 Content' },
        { tab: 'Three', content: 'Tab 3 Content' },
        { tab: 'Four', content: 'Tab 4 Content' },
        { tab: 'Five', content: 'Tab 5 Content' },
        { tab: 'Six', content: 'Tab 6 Content' },
        { tab: 'Seven', content: 'Tab 7 Content' },
        { tab: 'Eight', content: 'Tab 8 Content' },
        { tab: 'Nine', content: 'Tab 9 Content' },
        { tab: 'Ten', content: 'Tab 10 Content' }
      ],
    }
  },
  components: {
    TabNavigation
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

The component *(TabNavigaton-temp.vue)*:

```
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-tabs
      v-model="tab"
      v-bind="$attrs" 
      :align-with-title="alignWithTitle" 
      :background-color="backgroundColor" 
      :center-active="centerActive" 
      :color="color" 
      :fixed-tabs="fixedTabs" 
      :grow="grow" 
      :icons-with-text="iconsWithText" 
      :next-icon="nextIcon" 
      :prev-icon="prevIcon" 
      :right="right" 
      :show-arrows="showArrows" 
      :slider-color="sliderColor" 
      :vertical="vertical" 
    >
      <v-tab
        v-for="(item, i) in items"
        :key="i"
      >
        {{ item.tab }}
      </v-tab>
    </v-tabs>

    <v-tabs-items v-model="tab">
      <v-tab-item
        v-for="(item, i) in items"
        :key="i"
      >
        <v-card flat>
          <v-card-text>{{ item.content }}</v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-tab-item>
    </v-tabs-items>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "TabNavigation",
  data() {
    return {
      tab: null
    };
  },
  props: {
    alignWithTitle: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    backgroundColor: {
      type: String,
      default: "transparent" // default background color used in tabs within ADS documentation
    },
    centerActive: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    color: {
      type: String,
      default: "#121212" // default foreground color used in tabs within ADS documentation
    },
    fixedTabs: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    grow: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    iconsOnly: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    iconsWithText: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    items: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
    },
    nextIcon: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    },
    prevIcon: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    },
    right: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    showArrows: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    sliderColor: {
      type: String,
      default: "#CE0037" // default slider color used in tabs within ADS documentation
    },
    vertical: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  computed: {

  },
  methods: {
  },
  created() {

  }

}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see you didn't pass the items to the custom component, you can do it this way:

```
              <TabNavigation v-model="tab" :items="items"/>
```

Maybe there can be some other problem but the first step to pass items to the child component